# ASP.Net WebAPI with multiple optional route parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have a route that I want to use with multiple optional parameters, like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/crm/topline")]
public class MyController: ApiController
        [Route("{branchNumber?}/{salesNumber?}/{accountNumber?}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] string branchNumber = null, [FromUri] string salesNumber = null, [FromUri] string accountNumber = null) {
            log.Debug($"Get:{branchNumber}/{salesNumber}/{accountNumber}");
            return Ok($"Get:{branchNumber}/{salesNumber}/{accountNumber}");
        }
```

I know that it is possible to bind to the API like this:

`/api/crm/topline/?branchNumber=11&accountNumber=9795`

Using this format, I get a response of

> "Get:11//9795"

Is it possible to correctly bind to this using an http call like this?:

`/api/crm/topline/11//9795`

I have not been able to get that format to work, I end up with  a response of :

> "Get:11/9795/"

Indicating that this second format thinks the last parameter is the one missing, not the middle one.

Comment: What happens if you set the default value to an empty string?

Comment: No, duplicate slashes are reduced.  You could try to put in a -1 or 0 to indicate ignore this field in your code and then handle that to only use what is not set to your default setting.

Comment: @MarcusHöglund in the http get or in the server side code instead of null?

Comment: Try with [FromUri] string branchNumber = ""